Can I use built-in Microsoft DI in unit tests for init objects?
in unit tests for init and create the objects I would like to use buit-in Microsoft DI, is it good practice?

The point of DI is so your tests can mock those dependencies.

There are many different types of tests and even for "unit tests" answer depends on your definition of "unit test" and what you are actually testing. Answer also depends on approaches you have in your team, on libraries you use, some implementation details and etc.
In general I would say

if DI in some particular case makes your code more readable, smaller (questionable) and clean, then use DI
If you want to test some piece of code which is far away from DI (questions like "what is it exactly" and "should\shouldn't you do that" are out of scope) and DI usage here does not bring any benefit, then it is fine to create object manually

